# Why all the options on Rails syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby/Rails and it's been a struggle. An issue for me is the "loose syntax". The following is an excerpt from the Rails guide on testing:

> For historic reasons, the assigns hash uses string-based keys. So assigns[:person] won't work, but assigns["person"] will. To appease our yearning for symbols, though, an alternative accessor has been devised using a method call instead of index referencing. So assigns(:person) will work just like assigns["person"], but again, assigns[:person] will not work.

So we have

```
assigns(:person)
```

and

```
assigns["person"]
```

but not

```
assigns[:person]
```

But what about

```
assigns("person")
```

to complete the set?

So, what am I missing? Why is this level of flexibility a good thing?

Comment: It's not, your proposal would only muddle things further. Also, you're really not using comments correctly they apply to the line before them, not the line after them. It took me a few readings to figure out what you were talking about.

Comment: OK, I changed the comments, hope that's better. I'm not suggesting that the last option be added or makes sense. I'm just wanting to understand how I should think about the various syntax options for doing the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked which version is more idiomatic Ruby? The answer provided answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

The intent wasn't flexibility, the intent was consistency. Typically we use symbols as array keys in Ruby because they're faster than strings.

For "historical reasons", `assigns` didn't do that, so they simply provided a way to use symbols with `assigns` the way you do everywhere else.

It's not a good thing or a bad thing, it's just a thing.